# Which one of the following two ordinals is larger?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, ordinal-numbers, constructibility

We say that $\alpha$ is $\Sigma_n$-extendable (to $\beta$), if there is $\beta>\alpha$ such that $L_\alpha$ is a $\Sigma_n$ elementary submodel of $L_\beta$.

First ordinal: the least $\alpha_0$ such that there are ordinals $\alpha_0<\alpha_1<...<\alpha_{\omega^2}$, such that each $\alpha_i$ is $\Sigma_2$ extendable, and for any $i<j$, $\alpha_i$ is $\Sigma_1$ extendable to $\alpha_j$.

Second ordinal: the least $\alpha_0$ such that there are ordinals $\alpha_0<\alpha_1<...<\alpha_{\omega}$, such that each $\alpha_i$ is $\Sigma_2$ extendable, and for any $i<j$, $\alpha_i$ is $\Sigma_1$ extendable to $\alpha_j$, and $\alpha_\omega$ is the limit of $\alpha_i, i<\omega$.

Which one of these two ordinals is larger?

I'm able to prove that if we change $\omega^2$ to any smaller ordinal, then the second one is larger, but I don't know how to go further.

Comment: Is that standard terminology?

Comment: @AsafKaragila about $\Sigma_n$-extendable, I'm not sure. Others are standard terminology.

Comment: Yes, I meant about the "extendable", since it seems to be very close to "extendible".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second one is larger.

Because of the conflict of terminology with "extendible", I will say that an ordinal $\alpha$ is
*somewhere $\Sigma_n$-stable*
if there is $\beta>\alpha$ such that $L_\alpha\preccurlyeq_n L_\beta$.
Given a somewhere $\Sigma_2$-stable $\alpha$,
let $\beta_2(\alpha)$ be the least $\beta>\alpha$ such that $L_\alpha\preccurlyeq_2L_\beta$.

Let $\left<\alpha_n\right>_{n\leq\omega}$
be as in the second situation.
So each $\alpha_n$ (for $n\leq\omega$)
is somewhere $\Sigma_2$-stable,
and for all $m\leq n\leq\omega$,
$L_{\alpha_m}\preccurlyeq_{1}L_{\alpha_n}$,
and $\alpha_m<\alpha_{m+1}$ and $\alpha_\omega=\sup_{m<\omega}\alpha_m$.

Now note that for $m<n\leq\omega$,
we have $\beta_2(\alpha_m)\neq\beta_2(\alpha_n)$,
because otherwise letting $\beta=\beta_2(\alpha_m)=\beta_2(\alpha_n)$,
we would have $L_{\alpha_m}\preccurlyeq_2 L_{\beta}$ and $L_{\alpha_n}\preccurlyeq_2 L_\beta$,
and $\alpha_m<\alpha_n<\beta$.
But then actually $L_{\alpha_m}\preccurlyeq_2 L_{\alpha_n}$,
so in fact $\beta_2(\alpha_m)\leq\alpha_n$, contradiction.

Now by refining the sequence $\left<\alpha_n\right>_{n<\omega}$
if necessary, we may assume that $\beta_2(\alpha_m)<\alpha_{m+1}$ for all $m<\omega$ (though we might lose the minimality of $\alpha_0$). For let $\gamma_0=\inf_{n<\omega}\beta_2(\alpha_n)$ and let $n_0<\omega$ be the unique $n$
such that $\beta_2(\alpha_n)=\gamma_0$.
Now let $\gamma_1=\inf_{n\in(n_0,\omega)}\beta_2(\alpha_n)$ and let $n_1\in(n_0,\omega)$ be such that $\beta_2(\alpha_n)=\gamma_1$. Etc,
producing $\left<\gamma_i,n_i\right>_{i<\omega}$
with $n_i<n_{i+1}<\omega$ and $\gamma_i<\gamma_{i+1}$ and $\gamma_i=\beta_2(\alpha_{n_i})$.
By reindexing, we may assume that $n_i=i$ for all $i<\omega$, so in other words,
$\beta_2(\alpha_n)<\beta_2(\alpha_{n+1})$ for all $n<\omega$. So
$$ L_{\alpha_n}\preccurlyeq_2 L_{\beta_2(\alpha_n)}\in L_{\beta_2(\alpha_{n+1})}, $$
and
$$L_{\alpha_{n+1}}\preccurlyeq_2 L_{\beta_2(\alpha_{n+1})},$$
and the existence of $\beta_2(\alpha_{n})$
is then a $\Sigma_1$ statement about $\alpha_n$ which is true in $L_{\beta_2(\alpha_{n+1})}$,
and therefore true in $L_{\alpha_{n+1}}$,
and so $\beta_2(\alpha_n)<\alpha_{n+1}$.

Let $X$ be the set of all $\alpha<\alpha_\omega$ such that $L_\alpha\preccurlyeq_1 L_{\alpha_\omega}$
and $L_{\alpha_\omega}\models$"$\alpha$ is somewhere $\Sigma_2$-stable"; note the latter condition is equivalent to saying that $\alpha$ is somewhere $\Sigma_2$-stable
(in $V$) and $\beta_2(\alpha)<\alpha_\omega$).
So we have (after thinning out as above)
$\alpha_n\in X$ for all $n<\omega$,
and in particular, $X$ is cofinal in $\alpha_\omega$.

I claim that $X$ has ordertype $\alpha_\omega$.
For suppose not and let $\eta<\alpha_\omega$
be the ordertype of $X$.
Let $\beta=\beta_2(\alpha_\omega)$.
Then $L_\beta\models$"There is $\widetilde{\alpha}>\eta$ such that $L_{\widetilde{\alpha}}\preccurlyeq_1 L$ and $\widetilde{\alpha}$
is a limit of ordinals $\alpha'<\widetilde{\alpha}$
such that $L_{\alpha'}\preccurlyeq_1 L_{\widetilde{\alpha}}$ and $L_{\widetilde{\alpha}}\models$"$\alpha'$ is somewhere $\Sigma_2$-stable", and the ordertype of the set $\widetilde{X}$ of those ordinals is $\eta$''
(in fact this is witnessed by $\widetilde{\alpha}=\alpha_\omega$).
This statement satisfied  by $L_\beta$
is a $\Sigma_2$ assertion about $\eta$.
(It is not a $\Sigma_1$ assertion about $\eta$, because of the clause "$L_{\widetilde{\alpha}}\preccurlyeq_1 L$".)
Therefore $L_{\alpha_\omega}$ satisfies
the same statement about $\eta$.
Let $\widetilde{\alpha}<\alpha_\omega$ and $\widetilde{X}$
be a witness. In particular, $L_{\widetilde{\alpha}}\preccurlyeq_1 L_{\alpha_\omega}$.
Note then that $\widetilde{X}\subseteq X$
(in particular since if $\alpha'\in\widetilde{X}$
then $L_{\alpha'}\preccurlyeq_1 L_{\widetilde{\alpha}}\preccurlyeq_1 L_{\alpha_\omega}$, so $L_{\alpha'}\preccurlyeq_1 L_{\alpha_\omega}$).
But $\widetilde{X}\subseteq\widetilde{\alpha}<\alpha_\omega$,
and it follows that $X$ has ordertype $>\eta$, a contradiction.

So $X$ has ordertype $\alpha_\omega$.
Now let $\alpha^{(1)}_0$ be the first ordinal you defined and $\alpha^{(2)}_0$ the second. Maybe $\alpha^{(2)}_0<\alpha_0$ (because of the thinning out we did), but anyway $L_{\alpha^{(2)}_0}\preccurlyeq_1 L_{\alpha_\omega}$. From this and the fact that $X$ has ordertype $\alpha_\omega$, it follows that there are chains of the form required for the definition of $\alpha^{(1)}_0$ which appear in $L_{\alpha^{(2)}_0}$. Therefore $\alpha^{(1)}_0<\alpha^{(2)}_0$.

Comment: Thank you! You are always my hero!